# web.config: URL rewrite to remove directory

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-manager

So currently I've got the URL `websitename.com/posts/post`

and I would like to change it to `websitename.com/post`

I've been trying now for 3 days with no luck. Seen loads of stuff for .htaccess but not much for web.config

Apologies in advance as I'm sure I'm asking a really dumb question,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want. Put it in the root directory of your website. You could also change `Rewrite` to `Redirect` there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="posts" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                    <match url="/posts/post" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/post" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```